# My images are not displayed in block

Tags: views, blocks, media

My images are not displayed in block and attachment page,but displayed in the content
i check the views but don`t fixed i do anything with views and check permissions but not fix my problem.
Of course this problem when upload site from local to server is showing up. tnx.

[image]

what can i do ?? help